# remove all consecutive pattern in a string

Tags: regex, algorithm

I have a problem which needs to remove consecutive pattern in a string.

For example,

```
input: abcbcbcbcd
output: abcd

input: abcbcebcbcd
output: abcebcd
```

We may only consider the repeating pattern contains only 2 characters.

What is the best way to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what's you've been trying for this problem. And in the first example output should be **ad** - because **bc** are repeated pattern?

Comment: @DanielHao 4 `bc` is replaced with 1 `bc`. Giving `abcd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this regex:

```
(..)\1+
```

- Substitution

```
$1
```

| syntax | note |
| --- | --- |
| `(..)` | any two characters, capture them in group 1 |
| `\1+` | repeat group 1 at least 1 time |

Check the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/LYgpY1/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it in Python.

```
s = "abcbcebcbcd"
ans = ""
i = 0
while i < len(s):
    if len(ans) >= 2 and i + 1 < len(s) and ans[-2:] == s[i:i + 2]:
        i += 2
    else:
        ans += s[i]
        i += 1
print(ans)
```